# TCP/IP routes when using multiple DHCP servers

Tags: linux, router, gateway, private-network, tcp-ip

I have connected a computer (running Debian Wheezy) to two different DHCP servers (routers) through a cable and through a wifi device. If I look at the routes with `route`, I get the following result

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

If I perform a `traceroute` to some outside address, I see that it goes through the first router `192.168.2.1`. If I remove one route with

```
$ route del default eth0
```

and run `traceroute` to the same address, I see that is now uses `192.168.1.1`.

My questions.

Which of the two default routes is picked? Is it always the first one listed by `route`, or is it chosen every time according to some criteria?

If one default route has higher priority, how does it get chosen? Is it simply the interface that came up first during boot?

If I want to have a preferred route or even remove one of the two default routes, how do I do that? Is it sufficient to delete the route using

```
$ route del default eth0
```

or will this route be added again automatically each time the client is assigned a new address?

Some context to my questions: Computer X is attached to networks A and B using DHCP. The A-router should serve as a gateway for X but the B-router should not: the B-router should only allow X to communicate with computers on network B.

Comment: You need to look at policy based routing for linux (that term should be enough for google to give you appropriate answers).

Comment: @wurtel: Thanks a lot: searching for "policy based routing for linux" gave lots of hits.